# Error:java: module not found: javafx.application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2, java-10

I am using intellij 2018 with Java 10 and Javafx 2.0. I've also included Javafx.swing, javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml, javafx.control, and javafx.media into the project but I still get this error:

```
Error:java: module not found: javafx.application
```

Comment: can you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the JDK that comes with the updated intelliJ.

You may want to download the JDK again, and set it up again on the project structure.